# Project compatibility between .Net Standard and .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, xamarin

I got lost very quickly in all the moves from .Net Framework to .Net Standard to .Net Core.  Could someone please just tell me what I need to do to get my projects to work together?

Here's the situation:  I've got a simple web service written in ASP.Net that contains a set of classes built by Entity Framework from an existing database using a "scaffold" command.  The web service can respond to a request for a list of coils from a database.  The list is delivered as a JSON-serialized string.

I have a simple mobile app developed in Xamarin.  I want it to accept the JSON string and deserialize it into a list of Coil objects.  To do that, I need to add a reference to the web service project.  But when I try to do that, I get complaints that the targets of the two projects are not compatible.

The choices for target frameworks for the web service are .Net 5.0 and .Net Core 1.0 through 3.1.  The choices for target frameworks for the Xamarin app are .Net Standard 1.0 through 2.1.  I have been unable to find a combination of these choices that works.  What choices should I use that would enable me to add a reference to the web service project to the Xamarin project?

Or should I split the Entity Framework-generated classes out into a separate library?  That would probably be a better project structure anyway.  In that case, I'd have three projects.  The target framework chosen for the library would have to be compatible with frameworks chosen for the web service and the Xamarin app, but the framework for the web service would no longer have to be compatible with the Xamarin app's framework.

Or perhaps I should rebuild all of these from scratch.  These are all trivial projects, done mainly for education, although the Xamarin app might be useful in the real world.  Recreating them would be easy.  Again, if I did this, what targets should I use?

All development has been done in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I am not a Xamarin developer but I'll suggest you move the necessary EF Stuff code from the WebService to compatible states of the Xamarin project. Now after cutting out useful code for xamarin from the webservice project if the WebService project does not have a lot of code using third-party tools then create a new project which compatible with Xamarin and New EF helper project. Third-party tools sometimes don't have the latest frameworks compatibility!

Comment: .NET Standard 2.0 is compatible with both Xamarin targets and .NET Core. So that would be the best choice for sharable code until .NET 6 is out.